# Jenkins Slave "Connection Refused"

Tags: java, exception, jenkins, continuous-integration, slave

I'm trying to set up a Master Slave system with Jenkins. I created a new node on Jenkins and set it up. However, when I try to start the Slave Agent on the slave computer, it always throws an error, regardless of the method I use (web start or command line):

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to (myurl):(port)
```

(myurl) and (port) are placeholders.

...

```
Caused  by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

There is no firewall running, the port is open, and the master is indeed functioning properly. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like the placeholders were not evaluated correctly? Are you using the correct syntax?

Comment: Yup, I used the exact syntax that Jenkins told me to. I also tried the Web start so there's probably nothing wrong with the code itself

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error message and in my case the ssh server on the slave was just stopped.

I went on the slave server and checked the ssh status:

```
service ssh status
 * sshd is not running
```

I started ssh:

```
/etc/init.d/ssh start
service ssh status
 * sshd is running
```

Then I was able to restart the connection to the slave with jenkins.

You can also check the following point: the public key of your jenkins server ( /var/jenkins_home/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ) should be listed among the authorized keys of your slave server ( /root/.ssh/authorized_keys ).